# Comparing two arrays of Strings

Tags: java, arrays

I am a beginner in Java. I need to compare two arrays of string and find out if any value from the first array matches any value in second array?

Here is my function which does not work as expected,

```
public static boolean CheckStatAppearinLeftAndRight1(String[] array1, String[] array2)
{
    boolean b = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) 
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < array1.length; a++)
        {
            if (array2[i] == array1[a])
            {
                b = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                b = false;
            }
        }
   }
   return b;
}
```

Can someone please point out the issue here?

Comment: When a developer compare strings with `==`, he cries :D

Comment: ignorance is not a mistake ;), its very common mistake anybody does, i believe.

Comment: In Java, you don't compare Strings with `==`; use `.equals()` or `.compareTo()`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (array2[i] == array1[a])
```

should be

```
if ((array2[i]).equals(array1[a]))
```

Comment: Is there any big reason why you surround `array2[i]` with parentheses?

Comment: just bto be clear about application of equals method

Answer (score 0):

try>>>

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      int[] ary = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
      int[] ary1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
      int[] ary2 = {1,2,3,4};
      System.out.println("Is array 1 equal to array 2?? "
      +Arrays.equals(ary, ary1));
      System.out.println("Is array 1 equal to array 3?? "
      +Arrays.equals(ary, ary2));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array2[i].equals(array1[i])` instead of using == operator.
== operator compares the two references and would give you false.
equals() method is already overriden in class `String` which matches the exact characters from two different String Objects.

Answer (score -1):

```
    boolean b = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) 
    {

        for (int a = 0; a < array1.length; a++)
        {

            if (array2[i].equals(array1[a]))
            {
                b = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                b = false;

            }
        }
        if(b)
            return b;
    }
}
```